# How to remove black background when I decrease tab height in android

Tags: android, android-layout, background, tabs

I am using `tabs` in my android application.When I decrease my `tab` height,I see black background on that space.How to remove that?

[image: tab]

Thanks.

Comment: try this: android:background="@android:color/transparent" to tabhost

Comment: chances are that u have reduced the size of your tabs, but not that layout which contains those tabs. so check that out .

Comment: can you post the code for your layout file?